# FAQ update to reflect new downvote rule

Tags: feature-request, faq-update-request

The FAQ has not been updated with the information about down votes on questions not costing a rep point.

Answer (score 5):

It was already updated to show this.

> question is voted down  -2
>   answer is voted down  -2  (-1 to voter)

From [the reputation section of the FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation). We even have it on Gaming, and we're notorious for being late to the party for these kinds of things.

Comment: Remember that one time, when we discussed that thing in that place about the other thing with that guy? That was great

Comment: @Michael ~ No, not really. You should tell me about it again!